# Can I change a value of variable by using Siri Shortcut?

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I want to control my BLE Device with the help of Siri. Like "Fan On" or "Fan Off". So, Is that possible with the help of Siri Shortcuts?

Or is there any alternative way to Contorl BLE Device Fan with Siri.

I think if I am able to change a value of variable through Siri Shortcut then I can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now able to switch to On or Off my BLE Device Fan with the help of Siri Shortcuts. I just needed to to do one thing that I missed before: to pass the complete class to Siri Shortcuts Intent.

When I invoked Siri and said my own phrase, then Siri will execute the complete class code and off my device fan.

**The main thing that I missed is Pass the complete class to Siri Intent rather than passing only specific section of code or function.**